# Magnetar's magnetic field near a black hole (novice question)

Tags: black-holes, magnetic-fields, event-horizon, neutron-stars, binary-stars

Even light cannot escape the event horizon of a black hole. Now, imagine a magnetar orbits a black hole. The magnetar orbits too far to be ripped and consumed by the black-hole. However, its magnetic field is wide enough to reach the black hole's event horizon. This raises two questions:

1. Does the magnetic field experience blue shift when approaching the black hole and red shift when going away from it? What effect should I observe? (Outside the event horizon)
2. The event horizon intersects the magnetic field. The magnetic field cannot leave the black hole. Does the black hole strip the magnetar of its magnetic field?

Comment: The picture of the magnetic field getting pulled into the black hole might not be the right way to think about this. For example, the Reissner-Nordstrom solution describes a black hole with an electric field. The solution is static: the electric field doesn't get consumed. The Blandford-Znayek process  (an explanation for how black holes product astrophysical jets) involves electromagnetic fields that penetrate the horizon of a black hole. Those fields are produced by the plasma of the accretion disk, not by a magnetar, but some of the intuition might still apply.